# Find MacLaurin series and radius of $cos^2 \frac{1}{2}z$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$cos^2 \frac{1}{2}z$$

So I know that $$\cos{z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} -+ ...$$ and I have also seen that using taylor series formula that:

$$cos^2{z} = 1 - z^2 + \frac{z^4}{3} - \frac{2}{45}z^6$$

So can I just replace all z's with $\frac{1}{2}z$ and be done? Is that the maclaurin series here? What is the radius of convergence and why? I'm not sure how to calculate that...

Comment: Yup. I don't know if the Taylor expansion for $\cos^{2}{z}$ is correct or not, but if it is correct, then yes, you can replace $z$ by $\frac{z}{2}$ since $z$ is just a variable...

Comment: https://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-3-power-series/taylor-series/the-maclaurin-expansion-of-cosx/

Comment: It may be helpful to use $$\cos^2z = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cos(2z),$$ especially if you know the radius of convergence for the MacLaurin series for $\cos z$...

Answer (score 4):

$$\cos^2(z/2)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos z)=\frac{1}{2}(1+1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\frac{z^6}{6!}+....)$$

Comment: And the radius of convergence, like that of the cosine, is infinite. It all goes to show that not all “calculus” questions are best solved by doing calculus.

Comment: Mind replacing the x's with z's and I'll give you full credit?

Comment: Oh! yes, thanks @Jawan622